# Simulink sample time error when modeling analog circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, simulation, matlab, simulink

I’m trying to model a CMOS inverter as an ANALOG device (and, as far as I can tell, the input signals are all continuous time blocks), but I keep getting an error about sample time, which is weird because it shouldn’t be doing sampling at all, since this should all be analog.
This is my simulink schematic:
[image]

The last two blocks I created myself and wrote the code for.  The other blocks are from the simscape electrical toolbox.  I'm 99% sure the issue is with my custom block set-up, not how I used the simscape blocks, because I can actually get reasonable plots if I just use Simulink's built-in oscilloscope and XY blocks.

The error I keep getting is:

> The signal at 'Input Port 4' of 'CMOS_Inverter/MATLAB Function1'
> is a variable-size signal with a nondiscrete sample time. The sample
> time for any variable-size signal must be discrete.

I didn’t even set any sample times or use any discrete-time blocks at all I don’t think, so I don’t get why it’s even talking about sample-times.

Input port 4 is the "propagation delay" input on the plotting block. It's calculated using the following code inside the function definition for the `calculateMetrics` block: (`inputSignal`, `outputSignal`, and `timeVector` are all inputs to the function/block):

```
propagationDelay = 0;
riseTime = zeros(1,1);
fallTime = zeros(1,1);

% Calculate propagation delay as the time difference between 50% % levels of 
% input and output
inputMidPoint = (max(inputSignal) + min(inputSignal)) / 2;
outputMidPoint = (max(outputSignal) + min(outputSignal)) / 2;

inputTime = timeVector(find(inputSignal >= inputMidPoint, 1));
outputTime = timeVector(find(outputSignal >= outputMidPoint, 1));

propagationDelay = outputTime - inputTime;
```

`timeVector` is from the clock block I have connected to the relevant block in the schematic.  This is what I get when I double click it to see the parameters:

[image]

The parameters for V_DD are these:

[image]

V_in:

[image]

I’ve also played around with the solver settings a bit, changing the solver type from variable-step to fixed-step and then setting 0.01 as the step size, just to see if it fixed the problem, which it didn’t.  I’ve tried selecting various different solvers from the drop-down menu, but that doesn’t seem to make a difference either.

I should say that my professor suggested the problem might be the clock signal and the voltage pulse signals not being synchronized.  That would make sense if either of them were discrete time blocks. But they should all be analog signals, so I don’t really understand how that would apply (though I didn’t think about that until after my meeting with the professor was over).

What am I doing wrong here that's causing this sample-time error in an analog simulation?